# How to debug a kivy app in android?

Tags: android, kivy

I'm developing a kivy app in android.
After compiling the app and running it, if there is a
crash or sort of errors, how can I find the specific error?

I heard there is a log program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool you want is called logcat.

The doc is http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

It will display lots of log info from running Android programs, so it helps to apply filters such as the program name and log level.

From the doco:

> You can run logcat as an adb command or directly in a shell prompt of
> your emulator or connected device. To view log output using adb,
> navigate to your SDK platform-tools/ directory and execute:
>
> `adb logcat`

Comment: It's possible to get your own output into "logcat" by writing to `sys.stderr` in your Kivy program.

Comment: How can I use debugger for the python code in my IDE? I am using Pycharm. Or is reading logs the only way i can see whats happening in my code. Coz I am using buildozer to build and run my code in android phone.

Comment: Can you provide example of how to do that @Kingsley

Comment: can you give example of how the SDK platform-tools directory will look like?

Comment: @MurtazaHaji, the `platform-tools directory` contains `NOTICE.txt`, `adb`, `api/`, `dmtracedump`, ..., `systrace/`. On macOS, at least one installation goes to `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/`.

Comment: I am using buildozer which already gives me logs of my phone. Isnt there a better way than this, other than having to deploy app and check logs for errors? Like debugging the app in pycharm

Comment: @MurtazaHaji I hope there's a way to debug on Android. Please ask a new Question. Also consider filing a PyCharm feature request; I didn't see anything relevant on YouTrack.