# Embedding other data into a UDP video stream Python OPENCV

Tags: python, opencv, server, udp, video-streaming

I am trying to stream video to be anaylised on clients from a server.

I am using vidgears to create a ffmpeg UDP stream for the clients to connect to.

However, I need to have a centeralised frame count to be able to sync up all the data the clients give.

```
Client:    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://localhost:23000')   
while cap.isOpened(): 
    print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

Will only get me the frame count from the time the client connected. 

Is there a way to embed a timecode or frame count when I am stream out the video so I can sync them all up?
```

Server:

```
i = 0
output_params = {"-vcodec": "mpeg4", '-f': 'mpegts'}
streamer = WriteGearStream(output_filename='udp://localhost:23000', compression_mode=True, logging=True, **output_params)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap1.isOpened():
   i+=1
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, i)
   streamer.write(vis)
```

class WriteGearStream(WriteGear):

```
def __init__(self, output_filename='', compression_mode=True, custom_ffmpeg='', logging=False, **output_params):
    super(WriteGearStream, self).__init__(output_filename='temp.pm4', compression_mode=compression_mode, custom_ffmpeg=custom_ffmpeg, logging=logging, **output_params)
    self.out_file = output_filename
```

Does anyone know how to get a frame count that is synced with the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [VidGear](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Video Processing python library. *This isn't the right way to use the WriteGear API, nor it is designed for this purpose and therefore I'm afraid will not work.*

Kindly use VidGear's new **[NetGear API](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/wiki/NetGear) which is exclusively designed to transfer video frames synchronously between interconnecting systems over the network in real-time.** This new API implements a high-level wrapper around PyZmQ python library that contains python bindings for ZeroMQ - a high-performance asynchronous distributed messaging library that aims to be used in distributed or concurrent applications.

Comment: Does NetGear API support UDP protocol?

Comment: @Ahmad You want to broadcast to multiple clients?

Comment: If yes, then it does support that https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/netgear/advanced/multi_client/

Comment: Thanks, very useful link. However, I was curious to know if it supports unreliable transmission protocol (no error recovery techniques).

Comment: @Ahmad As TCP protocol works flawlessly in both One-to-One and One-to-many modes, I decided to remove UDP protocol. If you want to ditch error recovery techniques then simply switch to [PUB/SUB pattern](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html) by setting `pattern=2` in NetGear API.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful info.
I have tried to port the client app into an android apk using kivy and buildozer.
However, it does NOT run on android after deployment!
Are there any permission, settings and so on that are required to allow such streaming (between a server and mobile app) to take place?

Comment: Here you find the source code that I tried:
https://github.com/ahmad-hl/Tutorial-Kivymd

Comment: @Ahmad See this: https://github.com/rubar-tech/vidgear-kivy-android-opencv

Comment: @Ahmad Also, are you able to compile all NetGear API's dependencies in bulldozer without any error? Like simplejpeg?

Comment: Yes, and managed to create and deploy the APK on the android using buildozer. However, it doesn't run on android although it does on the PC.

Comment: After launching the android app, the server receives a message then the android client app freezes and the server exits with exception (msg: Client seems to be offline). 

Do you have an idea how to fix it?
Wireshark shows some packets from the server to the client, maybe 1 or 2 frames but they don't show up on the client app's screen!

Comment: I have tried this source code
but the problem above appears:
https://github.com/rubar-tech/vidgear-kivy-android-opencv

Comment: @Ahmad You need to debug apk itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597360/10158117

Comment: @Ahmad I'm guessing client(android app) never launched properly, or some runtimeerror is thrown. It may be missing some critical dependency.